# org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 3 [character 1 line 3]

Tags: java, json

I know there are few similar questions asked before but they have not been of any help, so sorry for asking again. I am using below code:-

```
 uri = new URI(http://url.com);
 tokener = new JSONTokener(uri.toURL().openStream());
 root = new JSONObject(tokener);
```

Now this aometimes is giving jsonObject Exception mention in title. I have tried to validate response from the url seperately and it is a valid json. Most of times this works, but sometimes it shows this exception. I am not able to pinpoint exact issue. Please help. Thanks.

EDIT1: The url response is quite slow and takes almost more than 2 minutes sometimes. And it always shows exception at same place everytime i.e. at 3 [character 1 line 3]

EDIT2: I tried to print **tokener.next(100)** and it showed the below error.
*java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 101 [character 102 line 1]*

When I tried to print **tokener.next(1)** It showed
*java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 2 [character 3 line 1]*

Comment: write response from url request to output( console or a file) before creating JSONObject, so you can find out what is going wrong .

Comment: @Bolzano please look at edit2.

Comment: i meant before the tokener , its obviously your response is not json formatted , its error probably a timeout exception. use this code to get url's content                                          
------->     
String line;
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();  
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URI(http://url.com).toURL().openStream()));  
while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) s.append(line);   System.out.println(s); <-------